# Connect ASP.Net web app with Azure Analysis Service Tabular Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-analysis-services

I am using Microsoft visual studio to build a ASP.Net MVC project connecting to Azure Analysis Service tabular model. The web app is published to both an Intranet Shared Folder and an Azure VM. (Not necessary both, just for testing)

Without the connection to Azure AS, the web app runs fine from both Shared Folder and Azure VM. However, after adding the connection information, an error returns after it is published (works fine on localhost during debugging).

Connection information is:

```
using ADOMD;
using ADODB;
```

........

```
strConn = "Provider = MSOLAP; Data Source = <asazure://westeurope.asazure.windows.net/xxxxx>; 
User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Persist Security Info=True; 
Impersonation Level=Impersonate;";

dbConn = new Connection();
dbConn.Open(strConn, "", "", (int)ConnectModeEnum.adModeUnknown);
```

Error is:

> *Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.*

Please advise how to fix it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I figured out is to install MSOLAP (amd64) onto the web server.
Reference: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-data-providers