# Front end options for SSAS Tabular Model

Tags: model-view-controller, frontend, ssas-tabular

I am developing an asp.net mvc application. Is there a way to use ssas tabular model in mvc? If not, what are my other options? Any help will be valuable. Thanks in advance

Comment: A couple of pointers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/486721/connect-tabular-ssas-to-asp-net-mvc  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808593/connect-asp-net-web-app-with-azure-analysis-service-tabular-model.  Also, if you Google up "asp.net mvc ssas tabular" there are a handful of YT videos (their usefulness, or otherwise, I cannot vouch for)

Answer (score 0):

There's an [ADO.NET provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/adomd/multidimensional-models-adomd-net-client/retrieving-data-using-the-adomddatareader?view=asallproducts-allversions) for Analysis Services.  So just like any other database, send queries (here DAX) and get data.

You would retrieve the data from a controller or a repository service registered with DI.

I have a sample here [XmlaControllerSample](https://github.com/dbrownems/XmlaControllerSample) of a .NET 6 web app with an API controller that retrieves data from a tabular model, and either maps it to a Model type or sends raw JSON to the client.

Comment: Thanks for replying. we have a on analysis service. anything for on prem version

Comment: Only the Auth is different for SSAS on-prem.  Same driver.